# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError for AutoloadedDriver40?

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, derby, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to Hadoop and Hive as well. I am trying to connect to Hive from Java by creating Java project and by adding all below required libraries

```
$HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*.jar
```

And below is my sample code to connect Hive database.

```
package com.stpl.hive.jdbc;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveSample {

    //private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        // Register driver and create driver instance
        Class.forName(driverName);
        // get connection
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("CREATE DATABASE newdatabase");
        System.out.println("Database userdb created successwdbfully.");
        con.close();
    }
}
```

While running i am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.stpl.hive.jdbc.HiveSample.main(HiveSample.java:18)
```

Am I missing any other jars to add in project? Please help me to solve this error. And i am using Hive 2.3.2 version. Please ask me if any other details required to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when definition of class doesn't exist at runtime.

> Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40

It seems you are missing driver library for derby, which may get resolved by including `derby-10.5.3.0.jar`.